# Elegant way to manipulate lists within list?

Tags: python

**EDIT**: I've changed my question slightly to make it more general whereby the i in p[i][j] can also change.

Very new to Python. I have lists [of equal length] within a list, which makes a 4 row by 5 column grid:

```
p = [[1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [1.0, 6.0, 6.0, 1.0, 1.0],
     [1.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 6.0]]
```

To manipulate each cell, what I'm doing now is this:

```
for i in range(len(p)):
    for j in range(len(p[0])):
        p[i][j] = p[i][j - 1] * c1 + p[(i + 1) % len(p)][j] * c2
```

My question is: Is there a more elegant way to write this instead of having a for loop within another for loop? Perhaps using lambda?

Comment: What do you want to do with the cells? I could probably figure out your intent from what you are doing, but it's not evident.

Comment: I want to manipulate them like in the code: `p[i][j] = p[i][j - 1 % len(p[0])] * c1 + p[i][j] * c2` but I want to get rid of the for within a for.

Comment: Maybe replace `range` with `xrange`.

Comment: `1 % x` is always 1 for x > 0, so I'm not really sure what has to be done here.

Comment: Slow down with the index arithmetic! `p[i + 1 % len(p)` gives a range error. Did you mean (i+1)%len(p) ?

Comment: @tuva - I suggested numpy earlier, but for what it's worth, this particular problem is actually more clearly written as nested loops.  If you weren't modifying the array in-place, you'd use `numpy.roll`. Because you're modifying it in-place, though, that isn't the same thing. If this code is a performance bottleneck, I can show you how to speed it up with numpy.  It's going to be a _lot_ less readable, though.  (And honestly, it's a perfect fit for cython, if you're running into performance problems.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want two nested loops, you can loop over the rows and construct each replacement row using a "list comprehension" (which also happens to use the keyword `for`):

```
for i in range(len(p)):
    p[i] = [ p[i][j-1]*c1 + p[i][j] * c2 for j in range(len(p[0])) ]
```

Since you're new to python, I'll add some suggestions:

a) There's nothing wrong with using two nested for-loops. In my opinion they are the best (clearest, most elegant) way to write your example.

b) You do realize that 1%len(p[0]) is a constant, right? But you probably don't realize that `row[i- 1%len(row)] == row[i-1]` EVEN in the case where p only has one column (because of the way index -1 works)

c) Somebody made the good suggestion to look at numpy Arrays (but then deleted the answer). I second it.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate without using indices:

```
for row in p:
    for j in range(len(row)):
        row[j] = row[j - 1 % len(row)] * c1 + row[j] * c2
```

I leave it to you to decide if there is a better way for you to operate on a single row.

If you want to cross-refer between rows and columns, then no, there's no especially better way to do this, unless you want to use something like numpy.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed my question slightly to make it more general whereby the i in p[i][j] can also change.

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of `map` and `lambda` might do the trick.